# Filter Multiple String/Extension With FileNameFilter

Tags: java

How can i filter more than one extension, FileNameFilter only allow one string at a time..

[FileNameFilter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html)

```
//  filter extension, but only allow filtering single extension.
//  i want to filter three extension like mp4, flv, wmv 

public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    private String ext;

    public GenericExtFilter(String ext) {
        this.ext = ext;
    }

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(ext));
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you create a subtype that accepts a `Collection<String>` of extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite your filter as below.

```
public class GenericExtFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String[] exts;

    public GenericExtFilter(String... exts) {
        this.exts = exts;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        for (String ext : exts) {
             if (name.endsWith(ext)) {
                 return true;
             }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can initialize it with multiple extensions: `new GenericExtFilter("mp4", "flv", "wmv");`.

The `accept` method will loop over the array, and if it finds a matching extension will return true, if not, false.

Comment: what is String... actually do, i never used this statement before..
could you provide link to it.. i failed to google it.. i am interested to apply this on my other program.. :)

Comment: Google for Java varargs.